# How many ways are there to distribute 12 distinguishable balls into 6 distinguishable bins?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

How many ways are there to distribute 12 distinguishable balls into 6 distinguishable bins so that 2 balls are placed in each bin ?

---

I solved it in the following way =>

$C(12,2) * C(10,2) * C(8,2) * C(6,2) * C(4,2) * C(2,2)$ and got the correct answer.

---

Can I apply Sterling formula of 2nd kind here ?

**I want to know how Sterling formula of 2nd kind is applied here ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying $S_2$ here will be quite convoluted.

As explained in another question of yours,
The number of ways  of getting exactly k different values when you throw n fair r-sided dice is

$\binom{r}{k}\cdot S_2(n,k)\cdot k! $

so to get exactly $6$ faces in $12$ throws of a normal die, $\binom66\cdot S_2(12,6)\cdot6!$ ways,
**but this would include $11$ patterns, viz.**

$\boxed 7\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 6\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 5\boxed 3\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\; \boxed 5\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 4\boxed 4\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1$

$\boxed 4\boxed 3\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 4\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 3\boxed 3\boxed 3\boxed 1\boxed 1\boxed 1 \;\;\boxed 3\boxed 3\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1\;\;\boxed 3\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 1$

$\boxed 2\boxed 2 \boxed 2 \boxed 2 \boxed 2 \boxed 2$

and we are interested only in the last pattern.

Now the number of ways for placing $12$ distinguishable balls in $6$ bins, the bins being indistinguishable  **except by occupancy**, the multinomial coefficient has to be divided by ${p! q!..}$ where $p$ bins each have $p_n$ balls, $q$ bins each have $q_n$ balls, etc, e.g.  for $\boxed 4\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 2\boxed 1\boxed 1$, there are $\binom{12}{4,2,2,2,1,1}/(3!2!)$ ways.

$S_2(12,6)= 1,323,652$ From this, if we subtract number of ways for $10$ unwanted patterns, we get

$1323652 - \left[\binom{12}{7,1,1,1,1,1}/ 5!+\binom{12}{6,2,1,1,1,1,}/4! ...+\binom{12}{5,2,2,1,1,1}/(2!3!) + ... \binom{12}{3,2,2,2,2,1}/4!\right] = 10,395$

$10,395$ is the number of ways to place$2$ each of $12$ distinguishable balls in $6$ *indistinguishable* bins,

So $10,395\times 6! = 7,484,400$, the desired answer.

But this looks like trying to catch your nose by bringing your hand from behind your neck !

Comment: If we are going to use multinomials at all, why bother using Stirling numbers? Furthermore, it is hard to figure out how the contents of the square brackets are generated. For one thing, I would think that $\binom{12}{5,2,2,1,1,1}$ would be divided by $1!\,2!\,3!$ rather than $3!$. Is there an algorithmic way to generate all of the $10$ cases, in case we wanted to extend this idea to other situations (or simply fill in the elided terms)?

Comment: Using the denominators that seem logical to me, e.g. $\frac{\binom{12}{5,2,2,1,1,1}}{1!\,2!\,3!}$, I get the correct answer for the sum in brackets, so there is probably a typo in the sum in brackets.

Comment: @Robjohn: **1.** Sorry, that was a typo, I have corrected. Thanks for pointing it out. **2.** The concept is that bins that have unique numbers of balls become distinguishable by occupancy, so just correct for bins that have the same number of balls, as we do, e.g. for finding the number of permutations of MISSISSIPPI. **3** Re why use Stirling numbers at all, I have already stated that it is a bit weird, in the last sentence of my answer.

Comment: What I meant by "why use Stirling Numbers at all" was that if we are going to use multinomial coefficients, we might as well just say the answer is $\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}$. That is why I avoided mentioning multinomial coefficients at all in that section of my answer, and only used binomial coefficients and Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind. However, it is still not clear how to figure out what goes in the square brackets in an algorithmic way. I figured out what goes there, but it required a lot of intuition.

Comment: @robjohn: Which square brackets are you alluding to, mine or yours ?

Comment: Since I have put nothing in square brackets, I guess they must be yours. If you are asking about my answer, it is clear what goes in the square brackets there. Nothing is elided without an explanation.

Comment: @robjohn: Sorry, I hadn't taken a close look at your work. Nice approach (+1). I will expand  my answer soon, to better explain.

Answer (score 2):

The number I think of immediately is the multinomial coefficient
$$
\begin{align}
\binom{12}{2,2,2,2,2,2}
&=\frac{12!}{2!\,2!\,2!\,2!\,2!\,2!}\\[6pt]
&=7484400
\end{align}
$$
which can be computed from binomial coefficients as you have done.

---

However, if you want to use [Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) and avoid multinomial coefficients, we can compute the number of partitions of $12$ items with no singleton using [Inclusion-Exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle): The number of ways to partition a set of $12$ items into $6$ subsets with $k$ specific singletons is
$$\newcommand{\stirtwo}[2]{\left\{#1\atop#2\right\}}
\overbrace{\ \ \ \ \binom{12}{k}\ \ \ \ }^{\substack{\text{number of ways to}\\\text{choose the singletons}}}\overbrace{\ \ \stirtwo{12-k}{6-k}\ \ }^{\substack{\text{number of ways to}\\\text{partition the rest}}}
$$
By Inclusion-Exclusion, there are then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^6(-1)^{k-1}\binom{12}{k}\stirtwo{12-k}{6-k}
$$
ways to partition $12$ items into 6 subsets with at least one singleton. Since there are $\stirtwo{12}{6}$ ways to partition $12$ items into 6 subsets, we have
$$
\begin{align}
&\stirtwo{12}{6}-\sum_{k=1}^6(-1)^{k-1}\binom{12}{k}\stirtwo{12-k}{6-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^6(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\stirtwo{12-k}{6-k}
\end{align}
$$
ways to partition $12$ items into 6 subsets with no singletons; that is, into $6$ pairs. However, this does not count the orderings of these $6$ pairs, so we need to multiply this number by $6!$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
&6!\sum_{k=0}^6(-1)^k\binom{12}{k}\stirtwo{12-k}{6-k}\\[3pt]
&=6!\left[{\textstyle\binom{12}{0}\stirtwo{12}{6}-\binom{12}{1}\stirtwo{11}{5}+\binom{12}{2}\stirtwo{10}{4}-\binom{12}{3}\stirtwo{9}{3}+\binom{12}{4}\stirtwo{8}{2}-\binom{12}{5}\stirtwo{7}{1}+\binom{12}{6}\stirtwo{6}{0}}\right]\\[9pt]
&=720\,[{\small1\cdot1323652-12\cdot246730+66\cdot34105-220\cdot3025+495\cdot127-792\cdot1+924\cdot0}]\\[9pt]
&=720\cdot10395\\[10pt]
&=7484400
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be 'technical', you certainly *can*, but they are not particularly interesting or adequate, for two reasons. The first is that Stirling numbers of the second kind count undistinguishable bins. The second is that they do not take into account bin size (apart from a bin being nonempty), only number of bins.

It would be much better if you used [Multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_to_multinomials) for this kind of problem (which is exactly what you did, if we carefully inspect your solution).

Comment: Well, Sterling can also be used if bins are distinguishable.

Comment: Yes, like I said. But not in a direct way.

Comment: Okk!! So, when size of bin is given, then sterling cannot be applied, but if it is given that each bin has atleast one ball then sterling comes into procedure, right ?

Comment: That is correct.